# one value from json in extjs

Tags: json, extjs, store

i use a store with a model. The jason has a value i want to use in an alert. The json is like this

```
{"slapen":[{"naam":"test","leeftijd":"43"},{"naam":"test2","leeftijd":"27"}]}
```

i want to display an alert for the first result. So when the store is loaded i want an alert like this

```
alert('De eerste winnaar is {here_comes_leeftijd} jaar');
```

so the number is what i want to show. Is this possible?

```
winnaars = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'stepDetails',
    pageSize: 20,
    loadMask: false,
    sortOnLoad: true,

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: detailURL,
        startParam: '',
        limitParam: '',
        pageParam: '',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'slaevents'
        }
    },
    autoLoad: false
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to the store's [load event](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-event-load) (either externally or by using the listeners config) and inspect the returned records there and act upon them.

```
winnaars = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'stepDetails',
    pageSize: 20,
    loadMask: false,
    sortOnLoad: true,

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: detailURL,
        startParam: '',
        limitParam: '',
        pageParam: '',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'slaevents'
        }
    },
    autoLoad: false


    listeners: {
        load: function( aStore, aRecords, aSuccess, aeOpt) {
            // Do something here.
            console.log(aRecords);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks! This gives all the records in my console. How can i get the "leeftijd" from the first result?